# Mysql query to find out third line manager

Tags: mysql

There is an `employee` table with columns `id, manager_id, salary, department`.

I want to know the maximum salary department wise for third line managers

Comment: What did you try? How does the manager table look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(salary) from employee where department = 'third line manager';
```

See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_max.asp